# Laravel add and remove Auth session variables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, session-variables

after user loging to the system(Auth::attempt success)

how to add additional data to the Auth session and remove additionally added variables
without logout user ?  (I mean without calling Auth::logout();)

is there a laravel methods to do that ?

**updated :** found a way to add but how to remove added variable ?

```
Auth::user()->setAttribute('key','value');
//Auth::user()->unsetAttribute('key','value'); ????? how to remove
return Response::json(Auth::user());
```

Comment: i don't think this will work cause that attribute you have setted do not will persist through the session

Comment: where to add this Auth::user()->setAttribute('key','value'); code to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer for this, you can unset variables, attributes etc, using php's `unset` function.

try this

```
 unset(Auth::user()->key);
```

check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php